# Checking a metric space separable or not.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The norm linear space C[0,1] with respect to supremum norm is separable. We can use Weierstrass approximation theorem and density of rationals to prove it. But what can we say when the norm is taking as the 'integration norm'(integral of f from 0 to 1) over C[0,1]. We know that it is not complete. But what about separability ?

Comment: A dense sequence for $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is going to be dense for $\|\cdot\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: You can probably do something with piece-wise linear functions with "corners" at rational coordinates.

Comment: Integral of $\lvert f \rvert$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ with the integration-norm is also separable.

For every $f,g\in C[0,1]$ you have
$$\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx\leq\max|f(x)-g(x)|=\|f-g\|_{\infty}$$
Hence if $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ with the sup-norm,
it is also dense in $C[0,1]$ with the 'integration norm'.